# How to connect two or more client desktop with one main desktop(consider as Server Desktop) and share database to each other using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sqlclient

this is dot Net C#  program,database is SQL2005. 
Problem is that it is working on Main desktop that is consider as SERVER desktop. but when I try to use its database in its client desktop then it gives me error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol)

**My Connection String**

```
"Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=hms;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True;"
```

other con string is

```
"Data Source=192.123.12.11;Initial Catalog=hms;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
Integrated Security=True;"
```

when I add the network library then it gives me error. otherwise working fine. I also replaced  etwork library  to network. but not working.

I also configured  MS-SQL server configuration, enabled TCP/IP  and named pipes, port :1433 ,

i installed SQL server in Server desktop and copy past  my all supported files in D drive. and I am using ip address of server desktop.

**In Client desktop** I  just copy pasted all supported application files in D drive. but did not install any sql software.

What happens when we do not specify network library in connnection string?

Comment: The error message simply means that you haven't enabled the proper protocol (TCP/IP) in your SQL Server configuration. Or that you failed to use the remote server's name in the connection string. The rest of the question doesn't make much sense

Comment: Also note that your connection string refers to the localhost, and doesn't have the real hostname in it.

Comment: At least I suggest you to install the client, not just copy files

Comment: i jsut fallow all steps that is mentioned in website.  first of all i enabled Both TCP/IP and  Named Pipes  in **local and Remote connection **. then configured all port 1433 in TCP/IP property.  and clear all dynamic port . but my window firewall is off.

Comment: and `Integrated Security=sspi; user=user;password=password;`

Comment: @MikeDebela what do you mean? You can't have both Integrated Security *and* a SQL username/password.

Comment: @pankaj don't blindly follow steps you found on a web site. Anyway, your "remote" connection string is wrong, it should be `192.123.12.11\\SQLEXPRESS`. `SQLEXPRESS` is the name of the SQL Server instance.

Comment: thanks Mike but when i try network library in connection string then it is giving me errr

Comment: is network library is necessary in connection string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes u can.

Comment: what happen when i ignore sql instance?

Comment: @pankaj, you don't *really* need network library

Comment: where is your answer user2946329

Comment: so please tell me when we required network library in connection string? please

Comment: Why the fixation with the network library? You use this setting only when you want to force ADO.NET to use a single protocol. Otherwise it will try both TCP/IP and Named Pipes. The error message is *very specific* - the TCP/IP protocol is *not* enabled on the server

Comment: help me please i did not get any solution

Comment: in sql server configuration are , Remote connection ,Both TCP/ip AND named  pipes  checked on showing me. then after how can i check TCP/IP is enabled or not. any  idea

Answer (score 0):

it was only connection string problem i solved it.
`return "server=Myserver; database=mydb;uid=sa;password=mypwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";`

i only installed MS-sql server in my SERVER machine. i shared a drive for all client machine. where i installed my app.

no extra configuration is needed .